# jQuery doesn't find by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I think Google Chrome console log is going to explain my problem best:

```
>> $(".single.portfolio")
[<article id=​"#js-single-item" class=​"post-883 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish hentry single">​…​</article>​]

>> the_element_id = $(".single.portfolio").attr("id")
"#js-single-item"

>> $(the_element_id)
[]

>> $("#js-single-item");
[]

>> document.getElementById("#js-single-item");
<article id=​"#js-single-item" class=​"post-883 portfolio type-portfolio status-publish hentry single">​…​</article>​
```

The weird thing is that getElementById works, but jQuery doesn't.

I tried to reproduce the problem in a fiddle by copying the whole HTML over and the code works as it's supposed to, so no trouble there. Most likely something is clashing together.

I'm looking for debugging tips. Thanks!

**Edit**: Typo. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
id=​"#js-single-item"
```

The `id` attribute shouldn't include the `#` sign. When you select `$('#some-id')` in jQuery, it's actually calling `document.getElementById('some-id')`.

You can do this:

```
$('#\\#js-single-item')
```

Also, don't.

Comment: OH MY GOD. I think it's time for me to go to bed. I didn't see the pawn sign! Hahaha :D

Answer (score 1):

You have `#` at the beginning of the id. since `#` is the selector for 'id' in jQuery, it will consider, it as element with `id = js-single-item`  not `#js-single-item`